# Isolating string in python list

Tags: python, string, list, google-finance

I'm using the google finance module to get stock data in Python. I would like to isolate the LastTradePrice from the list and convert it into an integer. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json

stockinfo = getQuotes('VSMGX')

stockdata = json.dumps(stockinfo, indent=1)
```

The stockdata looks like this

```
[
 {
  "ID": "904726512134516",
  "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Jan 8, 4:00PM EST",
  "Index": "MUTF",
  "LastTradeWithCurrency": "$22.26",
  "LastTradeTime": "4:00PM EST",
  "StockSymbol": "VSMGX",
  "LastTradePrice": "22.26",
  "LastTradeDateTime": "2016-01-08T16:00:00Z"
 }
]
```

Comment: You really want it is an integer? `22.26` would come back as `22`. Anything wrong with `[float(d['LastTradePrice']) for d in stockdata]`. BTW `info1` doesn't exist - did you mean `stockinfo`?

Comment: Yeah, I should be using a float. Thank you! Your answer worked

Comment: Oops, I just wrote the same code as @AChampion, token for token! Well, it _is_ an idiom :-)

Answer (score 1):

If all records have a last trade price, just use a list comprehension:

```
tradePrices = [ float(d["LastTradePrice"]) for d in stockdata ]
```

Edit: Convert it to `float` as @mattsap recommended. Well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want a float, since the lastTradePrice has decimals. Iterate over the list and extract the dictionary's value for the key of last trade price.

```
lastTradedPrices = []
for data in stockdata:
    lastTradedPrices.append(float(data["LastTradePrice"]))
```